# How to measure CPU single-core performance if I have different types of cores?

Tags: performance, cpu, benchmarking

I have a system of 4 total cores with the two of them being different than the other two. If the first two are type A and the other two are type B, how can I benchmark the single-core CPU performance of type A and type B? Any benchmarking tool suggestion would also come in handy.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Hard to answer as you don't say what operating system you're using. Many operating systems offer some form of [processor affinity control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_affinity), which might be what you're looking for.

Comment: I have a linux operation system and found out about taskset, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Using *taskset* so as to pin the benchmarking process to a particular core seems to do the job